# Xcode where to store 3rd party API secret / password / id

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am looking for best practice to store 3rd party API secret / password / id inside the code or Xcode project files

Answer (score 1):

You can use some obfuscation methods to keep your secrect/password/id more safe. Of course, it's not 100% safe, but it's better than to save in clear text in the source code because we may see it in the app binary file.

The steps are:

- Obfuscate your password and save into a file.
- Include this file into your project.
- When app launched, use the reveal method that is based on the Obfuscation on first step to get the clear text from your obfuscated data.

The obfuscated data can be also put directly to your class in the hex format.

You can find some obfuscation source code for objective-c or swift on cocoapods/github like: https://github.com/pjebs/Obfuscator-iOS

Answer (score 0):

Organize all the **API secret/password/id** in structure or an enum as:

**Swift:**

```
enum AppConstants {
   static let appSecret = "HJABFDQ4GH8Q9HHFUAB8RF"
   static let id = "YQW487HFIUGEFIB9BFQI3BICU"
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
#define appSecret  "HJABFDQ4GH8Q9HHFUAB8RF"
#define id         "YQW487HFIUGEFIB9BFQI3BICU"
```